# Converting Apache Arrow Table to RecordBatch in c++

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

I would like to obtain a `std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatch>` from an `std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table>` as

```
std::shared_ptr<arrow:Table> table = ...
auto rb = std::RecordBatch::Make(table->schema(), table->num_rows(), table->columns()).ValueorDie();
```

However the compiler complains that there's `no known conversion from  'const vector<shared_ptr<arrow::ChunkedArray>>' to 'vector<shared_ptr<arrow::Array>>'` since the `table->columns()` of course returns `vector<shared_ptr<arrow::ChunkedArray>>`. I can't seem to convert the `arrow::ChunkedArray` into `arrow::Array`. I've poured over the documentation but I can't, for the life of me figure out how to do this.

How do I go about it, and alternatively, is there another way to convert a `arrow::Table` into an `arrow::RecordBatch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a helper method [`arrow::Table::CombineChunksToBatch`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/d78b3224f5e6c579f62fe701abb4aba2a97a9ad9/cpp/src/arrow/table.h#L227) which should become available in the 7.0.0 release.

In the meantime you can do this:

```
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(std::shared_ptr<Table> combined, table->CombineChunks(/*Can pass memory_pool here*/));
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Array>> arrays;
  for (const auto& column : combined->columns()) {
    arrays.push_back(column->chunk(0));
  }
  std::shared_ptr<RecordBatch> batch = RecordBatch::Make(table->schema(), table->num_rows(), std::move(arrays));
```

Keep in mind that this is not a zero-copy operation.  Each column in a table is going to consist of multiple arrays.  When you call [`arrow::Table::CombineChunks`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/table.html?highlight=table#_CPPv4NK5arrow5Table13CombineChunksEP10MemoryPool) it will need to allocate a new array big enough for all the chunks and then it will have to copy data from each chunk to this new array.

If at all possible it is generally more performant to either keep the table or operate on it in a streaming fashion (e.g. use a [`arrow::TableBatchReader`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/table.html?highlight=table#_CPPv4NK5arrow5Table13CombineChunksEP10MemoryPool) and operate on one batch at a time).

Comment: First of all, thanks a ton for your help. Worked like a charm! I'm actually trying to read a CSV file into a `RecordBatch`. Given your comments though, I'm wondering if you'd also recommend reading a particularly large CSV file instead into a `Table`. If so, how does one choose/set an appropriate `chunk size`? If possible, please link some code that demonstrates reading a large file chunk-wise.

Comment: There are two CSV readers in Apache Arrow.  The [table reader](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/formats.html?highlight=tablereader#_CPPv4N5arrow3csv11TableReader4MakeEN2io9IOContextENSt10shared_ptrIN2io11InputStreamEEERK11ReadOptionsRK12ParseOptionsRK14ConvertOptions) reads the entire file into memory as one table.  The streaming reader (which, oddly, is not showing up in the documentation) reads a file one batch at a time.  Both readers read the file in chunks, configurable in the CSV ReadOptions class.  Both default to chunks of 1MB which seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I don't have a ready example of reading a large file chunk-wise but I will try and create one when I have some time.  I've added [ARROW-15328](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-15328) to track this.

Comment: I see. Much appreciated @Pace !